# Equivalent of enumerated type in Matlab

Tags: matlab, enums

I would like to define a data type in Matlab that can be 1 of 3 possible values. If I were doing this in C I would do the following:

```
typedef enum
{
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
    TYPE3,
} new_type_t;

new_type_t variable = TYPE1;
```

How can I achieve something similar in Matlab?

Ideally I want to have a Matlab class with a property that is restricted to some enumerated type.

My attempt at the Matlab code:

```
classdef Node
    classdef BoundaryTypes
        enumeration
            adiabatic
            convective
            conductive
        end
    end
    properties
        k
        c_p
        rho
        BC %type of boundary condition
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the documentation, you can define an [enumerator class](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html).

```
classdef WeekDays
   enumeration
      Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
   end
end
```

Comment: What if I wanted to make a property of a Matlab class restricted to some enumerator class? How would you suggest doing that?

Comment: @Hefaestion not sure exactly what you want, but in general I would think that you may be intersted in the part of the documentation above 'You cannot set the read-only property 'R' of SyntaxColors.'

Answer (score 1):

You would start by defining an enumeration class for your boundary types:

```
classdef BoundaryConditionType
    enumeration
        adiabatic
        convective
        conductive
    end
end
```

Then you would construct your node class:

```
classdef Node
    properties
        k
        c_p
        rho
        BC
    end
end
```

If you wish to restrict the class of `BC`, there are two ways. The first will only work in R2016a onwards:

```
classdef Node
    properties
        k
        c_p
        rho
        BC BoundaryType
    end
end
```

If you're using an older version, you can implement a `set` method that will restrict the class of the property:

```
classdef Node
    properties
        k
        c_p
        rho
        BC
    end
    methods
        function obj = set.BC(obj, val)
            assert(isa(val,'BoundaryConditionType'))
            obj.BC = val;
        end
    end
end
```